# Can't access articles array with where filter with Liquid in Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

In Shopify I am trying to access a specific article by its title with the following liquid code:

```
{% assign blogHandle = blogs[blogTitle] %}
{% assign introductionSection = blogHandle.articles | where:'title','introduction' %}
```

Although the article is not found. When I try to access the array with index i.e: `blogHandle.articles[0]` it works as expected.

What might be the issue here?